# error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, cuda, redhat

I am trying to execute MPI and CUDA code on a cluster. The code works fine on single machine but when I try to execute it on cluster I get error:

error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I checked my PATH and LD_PATH and it looks ok. I have a .bashrc file which contains following entries -

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/:/usr/local/lib/openmpi:/usr/local/cuda/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/ lib/openmpi/:/usr/local/cuda/lib

All the machines haves same installation of CUDA and OpenMPI.

I also have /usr/local/cuda/lib in /etc/ld.so.conf

Can anyone help me with this. This problem is really annoying.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to initialize the cluster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are sending a batch job on a cluster, please add commands like

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
ldd ./your_app
```

to your batch script. This should help to debug the problem.

Also make sure that you export environment variables in mpirun. For instance, in OpenMPI you would run your code with

```
mpirun -x LD_LIBRARY_PATH ...
```

Comment: mpirun -x LD_LIBRARY_PATH solves my problem. Thanks heaps. you made my day.